# UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate calls on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, popover

I'm attempting a project using the Xcode (version 9.1 9B55) Master-Detail template, using one Storyboard for both iPhone and iPad.

I want to use the built in popover segue, which ideally will show a popover when the size class is appropriate, or a modal view controller when the size class is compact (iPhone in portrait).

What I am finding is that it works just fine for iPad, but when I run it on an iPhone, you can't touch outside the popover to dismiss as I would expect.

When on iPad, popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover is called and all is well.

When on iPhone, the popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover never gets called and you cannot dismiss the popover.

To reproduce, I did this:

- Create new Master-Detail App
- New - File. Cocoa Touch Class, called MyPopoverViewController

In Storyboard:

Create new view controller, change class to MyPopoverViewController.

On MasterViewController, add bar button item "Popover". Control-drag from this to MyPopoverViewController. Set segue Kind to "Present As Popover". Set Identifier to "thePopover".

In MasterViewController.h, add UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate:

```
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController <UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate>
```

In MasterViewController.m:

```
#import "MyPopoverViewController.h"
```

In viewDidLoad, comment out two lines which create the "Add Button".

In prepareForSegue:

```
} else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"thePopover"]) {
    NSLog(@"MVC prepareForSegue thePopover");
    MyPopoverViewController *myPopoverController = segue.destinationViewController;
    myPopoverController.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
}
```

Add three UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate delegate methods:

```
- (void) prepareForPopoverPresentation:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController {
    NSLog(@"MVC prepareForPopoverPresentation");
}

- (void) popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController {
    NSLog(@"MVC popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover");

}

- (BOOL) popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController {
    NSLog(@"MVC popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover");
    return TRUE;

}
```

I tried this also, but all it does is force popover in portrait mode (which I don't want); doesn't change the lack of popover delegate calls and doesn't allow us to dismiss popover:

```
 -(UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller {
return UIModalPresentationNone;
 }
```

I'm hoping there is something simple I'm missing here. I have uploaded a sample project here, which is exactly what I've described above:

https://github.com/johnstewart/MasterDetailPopoverTestProject

How do I allow iPhone to also dismiss popovers by touching outside the popover?

Comment: PopOver is dismissed touching outside the popover. Your demo is completely working. I have tested in xcode 9.1 and iphone 8 plus simulator. Delegate method is called and succefully prints written in it

Comment: Jitendra - I just re-downloaded to confirm. I ran the project on iPhone 8+ simulator. Then rotated to landscape and touched the "Popover" button. A modal dialog comes up instead of a popover, and touching outside the dialog does not dismiss, nor call the delegate methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly your problem appears on iPhone 8 Plus in landscape mode.

In this situation, the presented popover actually is **not** a popover but a normal presented view. Visually it looks like a sheet that appears from the botton of the screen. In order to close such a view, you have to add your own button to do this.

If you want to show a real popover, you must implement:

```
adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:traitCollection:
```

to return `UIModalPresentationNone`. Note the additional parameter `traitcollection:`. `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` contains **two** similar methods. In your project you already implemented the method:

```
adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:
```

Change this to the former method and everything should work.

Comment: This is it!

I have implemented adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:traitCollection:
 in the MasterViewController, and the code works as I expected! 

I have added a test for if the device has compact or regular width (as my original intent - I want a popover only when regular horizontally, and a modal full screen when compact), and checked that code back into my test project for others' reference.

Thank you, mschmidt! Awarding bounty.